# How to use a Double Dispatch with overload in JAVA?

Tags: java, design-patterns, double, dispatch, concept

I'm trying to create a double dispatch in JAVA to use overloaded methods.

```
public abstract class ComposantOrdi {
    protected void equiv(ComposantOrdi c){
        Equivalence.equiv(this, c);
    }
}

public class Montage extends ComposantOrdi{
    protected void equiv(Montage montage){
        Equivalence.equiv(this, montage);
    }
}

public class Equivalence {
    public static void equiv(Montage m, ComposantOrdi c){
        System.out.println("Montage - ComposantOrdi");
    }

    public static void equiv(Montage m, Montage c){
        System.out.println("Montage - Montage");
    }

    public static void equiv(ComposantOrdi m, ComposantOrdi c){
        System.out.println("ComposantOrdi - ComposantOrdi");
    }
}
```

For the example i create two objects

```
Montage m2 = new Montage();
ComposantOrdi m3 = new Montage();

m3.equiv(m2);
m3.equiv(m3);
m3.equiv((Montage)m3);
```

The result is :

```
ComposantOrdi - ComposantOrdi
ComposantOrdi - ComposantOrdi
ComposantOrdi - ComposantOrdi
```

But i would like to use overloaded method from Montage class
and get something like this :

```
Montage - Montage
Montage - Montage
Montage - Montage
```

I probably didn't understand the double dispatch but could you tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Since `m3` is of `ComposantOrdi` type it can only invoke `protected void equiv(ComposantOrdi c)` method. Define it as `Montage` and you will have different output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what You are doing in your code is a **single** dispatch (not a **double** dispatch – explanation below) because only one concrete sub type evaluated at runtime is affecting the result (object wich passes itself as `this`).

In addition `ComposantOrdi` and `Montage` provide different methods (check the parameters: `ComposantOrdi` gets `ComposantOrdi` while `Montage` gets `Montage`). If you call the superclass' `equiv` method there is no way to get a result like *Montage - Montage* because every passed `Montage` is implicitly casted to a `ComposantOrdi`. Like this calling superclass' method the second part of your result cannot be anything else the *ComposantOrdi*.

Furthermore if you call the superclass' method the keyword `this` in

> Equivalence.equiv(this, c);

is triggered by the superclass which means even if the object is a `Montage` it passes itself as `ComposantOrdi`.

So: Calling the superclass' method can only produce the output *ComposantOrdi - ComposantOrdi*.

For an output like *Montage - Montage* you need to call the sub class' method `equiv` which means:

- you need to reference the receiver of the `equiv` call as `Montage` (see `m2` in your main, not `m3`)
- you have to pass in a `Montage` object

Because then the keyword `this` is triggered in `Montage` the first part of the output must be *Montage*. The second part is also *Montage* because Java does not implicitly cast objects if not neccessary. Thats why the overloaded method with to `Montages` as Parameters is selected.

So: Calling the sub class' method can only produce the output *Montage - Montage*.

The mixed version of the Equivalence's `equiv` method is never called.

---

**EXPLAINING THE DOUBLE DISPATCH MECHANISM:**

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding of the double dispatch mechanism. So let me explain it. I will start explaining a single dispatch before moving on to the double dispatch mechanism.

SINGLE DISPATCH:
A Single dispatch means you call a method of an object and the performed behaviour (the result of the method call) depends on the concrete type of the object. Generally this is called polymorphism and is implemented using abstract methods or method overriding.

Assumed you have a class system according to the picture below. The `Client` holds a list of `Shapes`. To paint all of them it loops through the list and calls `paint` on each  `Shape`. While a the class `Triangle` paints a triangle on the screen a `Square` paints a square. By not considering of which concrete sub type the `Shapes` are, the performed behaviour is determined at runtime.

In other words the result of the paint method's call depends on the concrete sub type of the derivatives of the `Shape` interface. The call of the paint method is a **single** dispatch because there is only **one** concrete subtype which determines the performed behaviour at runtime.

[image]

DOUBLE DISPATCH: Using the **double** dispatch mechanism the performed behaviour is affected by **two** concrete sub types at runtime. Like this you span a behaviour matrix which is evaluated dynamically.

If you modify the class system according to the picture below the paint mechanism triggered by the client is dependent on two objects – `Shape` and a `Painter`. The client calls the `paint` method and injects its `Painter`. Then the `Shape` passes itself as `this` in one of the overloaded methods of the `Painter`.

Like this the `Client` triggers the paint mechanism without knowing what kind of shape in what color is painted. If for example its painter is a `GreenPainter` and the `Shape` is a `Triangle` then a green triangle appears on the screen.

In this example the double dispatch mechanism is triggered by the call of the `Shapes`' `paint` method.

You should have a look at the **visitor pattern** which uses the double dispatch mechanism.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

General JVMs only use single dispatch: the runtime type is only considered for the receiver object; for the method's parameters, the static type is considered.

If you want multiple dispatch for your parameters, and you want to stick with Java, take a look at [MultiJava](http://multijava.sourceforge.net/)

If your goal is to stick with plain, vanilla java, read up on other design patterns such as, Strategy, Visitor, Observer. These can often solve the same problems as multiple dispatch